# Azure data explorer data purge

Tags: azure-data-explorer

As per [Azure Data Explorer's purge guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/concepts/data-purge), the process should not be used for deleting massive quantity of data. What defines "massive"? Trying to delete ~70K rows results in the query timeout.

Comment: Your description is bit confusing since when you run a purge command you get back an operation id which you can use it to check the status of the purge operation. Can you provide more details for the error that you got?

Comment: When we run a 2 step purge command, then we first get a verification token. That verification token is then used to run the purge command which gives an opreation Id. In my case, the first step itself (i.e. one of getting the verification token) is timing out.

Comment: You're probably hitting a request timeout (default is 10m for control commands - see this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/concepts/querylimits#limit-on-request-execution-time-timeout). This timeout is not enforced on the actual purge command, only on the 1st step. Please verify your purge predicate using a regular query to the engine endpoint, while increasing timeout limits (details in the link). Once verified, invoke the purge command to the DM endpoint using the 'noregrets' flag.